# ML technique to find patterns in time series trends in data (Python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pattern-matching, grouping, cluster-analysis

I have quarterly time series data covering a 5 year period (20 quarters). This data is split into lots of rows (>1000). What I'd like to do is see if there is any natural grouping for these rows based on their growth rates over time.

For example, whether they can be clustered into different 'shapes' of trendline (e.g. there could be a group with 2 years of flat-line growth, followed by 3 years of consistent growth and another group that has declined consistently over the 5 years). Is there any way I can do this using an unsupervised ML model?

Apologies if this question is basic / unclear - I'm not really very familiar with ML techniques

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.